# How to execute jmeter script using maven through eclipse

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I want to execute Jmeter script through a Maven project, but during the test I am getting some error.

Error says -
 'groupId' is missing. 
'artifactId' is missing
'version' is missing.
Please provide the step by which I can execute performance test run though Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Minimalistic `pom.xml` file looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.blazemeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvn-jmeter</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>maven-jmeter-demo</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

You may have to add other dependencies if needed.

References:

- [JMeter Maven Plugin](http://jmeter.lazerycode.com/)
- [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)